# Get the Count of a SubQuery

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to count the result of some SQL query which I have no control over.  My idea is to wrap the inner SQL with a wrapper count query.  The outer SQL is quite simple, here is what I got:

```
select count(*) from ( x ) as CountQuery
```

where x is whatever the inner SQL goes.  The problem with this is some query would crash, namely IF ELSE END.

How do I craft a wrapper SQL that will successfully wrap around any SQL?

Here is an example of one of the inner SQL I need to count:

```
IF null <> 'PIPELINE_STAGE'
BEGIN
WITH cnts AS
(
SELECT 
       o.[OPPORTUNITY_ID]
      ,[OPPORTUNITY_NAME]
      ,[OPPORTUNITY_DETAILS]
      ,[IMAGE_URL]
      ,OPPORTUNITY_VALUE
      ,[PROBABILITY]
      ,[BID_CURRENCY]
      ,[BID_AMOUNT]
      ,[BID_TYPE]
      ,[BID_DURATION]
      ,[FORECAST_CLOSE_DATE]
      ,o.[CATEGORY_ID]
      ,c.CATEGORY_NAME
      ,c.BACKGROUND_COLOR
      ,o.[PIPELINE_ID]
      ,o.[STAGE_ID]
      ,[OPPORTUNITY_STATE]
      ,[RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID]
      ,u.[First_Name]
      ,u.[Last_Name]
      ,o.[VISIBLE_TO]
      ,o.VISIBLE_TEAM_ID
      ,o.[DATE_CREATED_UTC]
      ,o.[DATE_UPDATED_UTC]
      ,o.OWNER_USER_ID
      ,o.IMPORT_ID
      ,Follow_id
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'OPPORTUNITY_NAME' THEN OPPORTUNITY_NAME END,
  CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'RESPONSIBLE_USER' THEN ISNULL(u.[FIRST_Name], 'zz') END,
  CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'FORECAST_CLOSE_DATE' THEN Forecast_Close_Date END,
  CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'DATE_CREATED' THEN o.[DATE_CREATED_UTC]  END,
  CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'FORECAST_CLOSE_DATE_DESC' THEN Forecast_Close_Date END DESC,
  CASE WHEN @sortOrder = 'DATE_CREATED_DESC' THEN o.[DATE_CREATED_UTC]  END DESC
       ) as intRow, 
     COUNT(o.INSTANCE_ID) OVER() AS Count
  FROM [Insightly].[dbo].[Opportunity] o with (nolock)
  LEFT JOIN [Insightly].[dbo].[Reference.Category] c with (nolock)
  on o.CATEGORY_ID = c.CATEGORY_ID AND c.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId
  LEFT JOIN [Insightly].[dbo].[User] u WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON u.USER_ID = o.RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID AND u.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId
  LEFT JOIN [Insightly].[dbo].[User.Follow] uf WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON (o.OPPORTUNITY_ID = uf.OPPORTUNITY_ID AND uf.USER_ID = @currentUserId AND uf.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId)
WHERE o.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId AND TEMPORARY = 0 
AND (@userId IS NULL OR [RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID] =@userId) AND (@categoryId IS NULL OR c.CATEGORY_ID = @categoryId)
AND (@importId IS NULL OR o.IMPORT_ID = @importId)
AND OPPORTUNITY_STATE in @opportunityState)
SELECT * FROM cnts
WHERE intRow BETWEEN @skip AND @take
END
ELSE
BEGIN
WITH cnts AS
(
SELECT 
       o.[OPPORTUNITY_ID]
      ,[OPPORTUNITY_NAME]
      ,[OPPORTUNITY_DETAILS]
      ,[IMAGE_URL]
      ,OPPORTUNITY_VALUE
      ,[PROBABILITY]
      ,[BID_CURRENCY]
      ,[BID_AMOUNT]
      ,[BID_TYPE]
      ,[BID_DURATION]
      ,[FORECAST_CLOSE_DATE]
      ,o.[CATEGORY_ID]
      ,c.CATEGORY_NAME
      ,c.BACKGROUND_COLOR
      ,o.[PIPELINE_ID]
      ,o.[STAGE_ID]
      ,[OPPORTUNITY_STATE]
      ,[RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID]
      ,u.[First_Name]
      ,u.[Last_Name]
      ,o.[VISIBLE_TO]
      ,o.VISIBLE_TEAM_ID
      ,o.[DATE_CREATED_UTC]
      ,o.[DATE_UPDATED_UTC]
      ,o.OWNER_USER_ID
      ,o.IMPORT_ID
      ,Follow_id
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ISNULL(p.Pipeline_Name, 'zz'), ISNULL([Pipeline.Stage].Stage_Order, 999)
       ) as intRow, 
     COUNT(o.INSTANCE_ID) OVER() AS Count
  FROM [Insightly].[dbo].[Opportunity] o with (nolock)
  LEFT JOIN [Insightly].[dbo].[Reference.Category] c with (nolock)
  on o.CATEGORY_ID = c.CATEGORY_ID AND c.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId
  LEFT JOIN [Insightly].[dbo].[User] u WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON u.USER_ID = o.RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID AND u.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId
  LEFT JOIN [Insightly].[dbo].[User.Follow] uf WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON (o.OPPORTUNITY_ID = uf.OPPORTUNITY_ID AND uf.USER_ID = @currentUserId AND uf.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Pipeline.Stage] with(nolock) ON o.PIPELINE_ID = [Pipeline.Stage].PIPELINE_ID AND o.STAGE_ID = [Pipeline.Stage].STAGE_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Pipeline] p with(nolock) ON o.PIPELINE_ID = p.PIPELINE_ID AND p.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId
WHERE o.INSTANCE_ID = @instanceId AND TEMPORARY = 0 
AND (@userId IS NULL OR [RESPONSIBLE_USER_ID] =@userId) AND (@categoryId IS NULL OR c.CATEGORY_ID = @categoryId)
AND (@importId IS NULL OR o.IMPORT_ID = @importId)
SELECT * FROM cnts
WHERE intRow BETWEEN @skip AND @take
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a temp table based on the query and then count the rows in it.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_results
<whatever query you have>;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_results;
```

Comment: Not if the temp table resides in memory.  Depending on the platform, you may be able to specify this in code.  The OP has not provided enough info to determine this.